# AWS Amplify, await Auth.currentUserInfo

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I need to get some custom attributes from Cognito, and to do something with that info.

I have this function:

```
const getMyAttribute = async (): string => {
  const userInfo = await Auth.currentUserInfo();
  console.log('userInfo', userInfo);
  return userInfo.attributes['custom:myAttribute']
};
```

And I'm calling it here in some React Component with:

```
const myAttribute = getMyAttribute();
console.log('myAttribute:', myAttribute); // Here is weird output
// Here I need to do something with `myAttribute`
```

In console.log I'm getting this:

```
myAttribute:  {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}

userInfo: {"attributes": {"custom:myAttribute": "6", "email": "testpending4@test.cl", "sub": "etc..."}, ... rest of user info data from Cognito}
```

So, I'm getting some weird output in `myAttribute` at calling the function, but the real data from Cognito comes later on `userInfo`

How can I get the real data on `myAttribute` as well?

Comment: A comment. If I call `getMyAttribute` with await, and I put  async on the React component function, I get the data in order, but this produces a conflict with a HOC that iis wrapping my component with some props

Answer (score 0):

At your call site for `getMyAttribute()` it looks like you're missing an `async` keyword.

Does changing the line
`const myAttribute = getMyAttribute();`
to
`const myAttribute = async getMyAttribute();` improve the output?

Answer (score 0):

From your code, getMyAttribute is promise method. That's why you get asynchronize process when call it. To call it properly, you must work with async - await and you have done with other issue. Other way, have you tried this ?

```
let myAttribute;
getMyAttribute().then(attribute => {
    myAttribute = attribute;
})
```